# Plotting a circle divided in thirds with different colours each_ MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure, geometry

I want to draw a circle divided in thirds and fill each third with a different RGB color, in MATLAB.

I started by drawing a circle and filling it all with one colour. Then I divided that circle in 3 equal areas. Now I am trying to give a different color to each 'slice' of the circle. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
% FilledCircle3 : function that takes 5 inputs
% 
% Call the function:
% FilledCircle3(x0,Row,Radius,N,Color)
% 
% Inputs Types
% ------------
%  x0 - Integer, Float
%  y0    - Integer, Float
%  Radius - Integer, Float
%  N      - Integer
%  Color  - Character String
% 
% Notes on N: The more N increases, the more accurate  is the circle
%             The standard value for N is 256
% 
% Notes on Color: 
%  'b'     blue          
%  'g'     green         
%  'r'     red           
%  'c'     cyan            
%  'm'     magenta       
%  'y'     yellow       



function []=FilledCircle3(x0,y0,Radius,N,Color)

if(N<=1)
    error('N must be greater than 1');
end

if (Color ~='b') && (Color ~='g') && (Color ~= 'r') && (Color ~='c') && (Color ~='m') && (Color ~='y') 
    error('This is not an available color');
end
hold on
axis equal
t=(0:N)*2*pi/N; %t=-pi:0.01:pi
x=Radius*cos(t)+x0;
y=Radius*sin(t)+y0;
plot(x,y,Color, fill(x,y,Color));
hold on 

% Divide circle into 3 sectors
n=3
tet=linspace(-pi,pi,n+1)
xi=r*cos(tet)+x0
yi=r*sin(tet)+y0
for k=1:numel(xi)
plot([x0 xi(k)],[y0 yi(k)])
hold on
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `fill` to create filled shapes.

```
thetas = linspace(-pi, pi, n+1);

% Specify any colors that you want
colors = hsv(n);

for k = 1:n
    tt = linspace(thetas(k), thetas(k+1));
    xi = r * cos(tt) + x0;
    yi = r * sin(tt) + y0;

    fill([xi(:); x0], [yi(:); y0], colors(k,:));

    hold on
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there any reason why you chose hsv colors @Suever ?

Comment: @Mraquel The colors I chose are arbitrary. You can use any colors that you want.